# create shortcodes for posts

Tags: shortcode

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(
'post_type' => 'my_posttype',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'orderby' => 'title',
'order' => 'ASC'
));

while ($query->have_posts()) {
    $query->the_post();
    $shortcodename = __to_eng(get_the_title());
    $shortcodefuncname = $shortcodename.'_shortcode';
    $img24x24 = get_the_post_thumbnail_url('24x24');
    $shortcodefuncname = function(){
        global $shortcodename;
        return $sortcodename;
    };
    add_shortcode($shortcodename, $shortcodefuncname);
}
wp_reset_query();
```

this is my code for shortcode of posts. when I trying to press that shortcode [my_post_which_i_want] it return me my last post.
What is wrong?

Comment: You are creating `shortcode`  but you don't have function definition for `$shortcodefuncname` to return our post i.e your `shortcode` function doesn't exist. For each added function name you have to create function to return the post so that you can use something like this `[my_post_which_i_want] `.

Comment: this is basic php question. answe:r do not ever use globals

Answer (score 0):

Your `shortcode` name and `shotrcode_function_name` are dynamic i.e vary with post name, which cause problem if you have same post title for two post. Also, you may not know or may be confused what `shortcodes` are available.
I recommend to do this if your post title will always be unique.

```
while ($query->have_posts()) {
    $query->the_post();

    $shortcodename = strtolower( __to_eng(get_the_title()) ); 
    str_replace(' ', '_', $shortcodename); // your post name, replaced white space  with '_'
    $shortcodefuncname = $shortcodename.'_shortcode'; // available shortcodes
    $img24x24 = get_the_post_thumbnail_url('24x24');

    $attribute = array('post_id' => get_the_ID(), 'post_title' => get_the_title(), 'image_url'=>$img24x24, 'post_content' => get_the_content());

    $shortcode['attribute'] = $attribute;
    $shortcode['func_name'] = $shortcodefuncname;
    $shortcode['shortcode_name'] = $shortcodename;
    $shoortcodes[] = $shortcode;

}
wp_reset_query();


foreach ( $shortcodes as $shortcode ){
     function $shortcode['func_name']( $atts ){
     $atts = shortcode_atts( array(  //defaults atts for shortcode
           'image' => 'show',
           'content' => 'show'
          ), $atts );
          $return = '<h3>'.$shortcode['attribute']['post_title'].'</h3>';
          if( !($atts['image']=='hide') ){ // you can set image="hide" in shortcode
              $return .= '<img src="'.$shortcode['attribute']['image_url'].'"/>';
          }  
          if( !($atts['content']=='hide') ){
             $return .= '<p>'.$shortcode['attribute']['post_content'].'</p>';
           }
           return $return;         

     }
     add_shortcode($shortcode['shortcode_name'], $shortcode['func_name']);
}
```

Your short code is ready. You can use

```
[my_post_which_i_want] // my_post_which_i_want is post title lowercased and white space replaced with '_'
```

Comment: while I think the idea of the OP is just a long term nightmare, in principal there is no problem with creating shortcodes dynamically as long as you are consistent about it, and the way the OP want to use it has merit.